# Moment JS. Trying to find how to select every single day from all the weeks of the whole year

Tags: javascript, calendar, momentjs

I've read some documentation from moment js, and I haven't realized how to implement it. I have only found the way to catch the days from the current week. What I am trying it is to grab every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and Saturday of the whole year

This code just grab every single day of the current week

```
var Monday = moment.weekdays(1);
    var Tuesday = moment.weekdays(2);
    var Wednesday = moment.weekdays(3);
    var Thursday = moment.weekdays(4);
    var Friday = moment.weekdays(5);
    var Saturday = moment.weekdays(6);
```

Comment: You already asked this question and it has been put on hold, please avoid asking the same question again and again, try to edit the previous one adding more details and showing what you tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment JS. Looking for how to select every Monday of a year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636691/moment-js-looking-for-how-to-select-every-monday-of-a-year)

Answer (score 0):

Advance the date by 7 days, 52 times in a loop (and work out the odd change). Assuming today is the first Monday of the year, this will get you all Mondays:

```
var theMondays = [];
for ( var weeki = 0; weeki < 53; weeki++ ) {
    theMondays.push( moment().add( weeki * 7, 'days') );
}
```

Use one of the following to find your way around the beginning of the year:

```
moment().startOf('year');    // set to January 1st, 12:00 am this year
moment().startOf('month');   // set to the first of this month, 12:00 am
moment().startOf('quarter');  // set to the beginning of the current quarter, 1st day of months, 12:00 am
moment().startOf('week');    // set to the first day of this week, 12:00 am
moment().startOf('isoWeek'); // set to the first day of this week according to ISO 8601, 12:00 am
moment().startOf('day');     // set to 12:00 am today
```